# Getting data using OAI-PMH from an insitutional repository

Tags: java, xml-parsing, oai

I'm developing an application where I've requested data from an external institution's website. They have informed me that the data will be provided by OAI-PMH.

Could someone show me some sample code in *Java* how data is extracted from a OAI-PMH ?

I wonder how different it is from reading and parsing XML data.

Thank you.

Warmest wishes,
Shoubhik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Java implementation, for example, you could use some already existent library, like [XOAI](https://github.com/lyncode/xoai) with an easy to use API. There are some provided [samples](https://github.com/lyncode/xoai/wiki/Service-Provider).

To extract metadata from each Record you could use a XML Parser or a XML bind approach (JAXB). For other languages, like PHP and Perl there are also other alternatives.